# Response XML showing unicode charcarter as question mark

Tags: javascript, java, xml, unicode

My XML text response is showing a question mark instead of a Unicode character even when the response says the charset is UTF-8

When writing the response XML the Unicode character is showing as  "`&#9675;`"

I expect to see the white bullet but I'm getting a question mark instead, what am i missing?

EDIT: Here is the ajax call located in one function that generates the xml response and below is the function that processes that response:

```
var ajaxCall = new Ajax.Request( url5, {method: 'post', parameters: params5, onComplete: this.populateDropDown.bind(this) } );

populateDropDown: function( request )
    {
    var rowNodes    = getChildren( request.responseXML, "LOOKUPFIELDS", "ROW" );
    if (rowNodes == null){
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rowNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var rowNode = rowNodes[i];
        var id          = getChildNodeValue( rowNode, 'CODENAME' );
        var name        = getChildNodeValue( rowNode, 'CODENAME' );
        var historical  = getChildNodeValue( rowNode, 'HISTORICAL' );
        if (historical == 'T'){
            name = name + ' [H]';
        }
        this.searchManager.addItemToSelector( this.valueEl, name, id );
    }
},
```

When looking at the request.responseXML the unicode character is seen as question mark

I found out that when writting the xml response text on the response object in tha java servlet side, the string containing the xml text has the white bullet but after doing

```
 response.write( xmlWriter.toString() );
```

the white bullet changes to a question mark, what am I missing there?

Comment: Please show the code that creates the problem.

Comment: Added the my code

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: The ajax call is done to a servlet, that generates the xml response